# Return limited records from SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple SQL view that has a SELECT statement returning several fields from table(s). The view, named vw_UserData, looks something like this:

```
SELECT client.Lastname, client.Firstname, client.ClientID, client_image.Image 
FROM client
LEFT OUTER JOIN client_image ON client.ClientID = client_image.ClientID
WHERE client_image.Description LIKE '%PHOTO%
```

The image field is (image/blob) field and the more records the view returns, the longer it takes to run.

If I run this query by adding TOP 100 to it and specifying a lastname in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT TOP 100 client.Lastname
...
WHERE client_image.Description LIKE '%PHOTO%
AND client.lastname = 'smith'
```

It will return all the records with smith as a lastname (count = 64 records).

However, when run the SELECT using the view (with the TOP 100) and removing the lastname from the WHERE

```
SELECT * FROM vw_UserData WHERE Lastname = 'smith'
```

I only get back one record!  Why?  Furthermore if I have a Todd Smith and run

```
SELECT * FROM vw_UserData WHERE Lastname = 'smith' and Firstname = 'todd'
```

I get back no records. I can't seem to run the view with the TOP 100 in it and run a SELECT using the view.  I want to be able to limit the number of records returned if no WHERE criteria by the application using the view is specified - i.e. I don't want to return all the records, but limit them.  However, if criteria is specified, such as lastname or firstname, I want to bring back all those record - up to 100 which there aren't normally more than that for our current data.

I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you've put `TOP 100` inside the view? Well the view is going to pick a random 100 records where `Description LIKE '%PHOTO%` which may or may not contain the surname "smith" - hence why it doesn't return the expected results.

Comment: You are probably better off with a stored procedure and a couple of parameters for the name search / filter

Comment: Perhaps you would do better to leave the blobs behind and create another view that you can `join` to retrieve the blobs as needed, e.g. `ClientSummaries` with all of the columns except `Image` and `ClientImages` with just `ClientId` and `Image`.

Comment: I find your question quite confusing. can you create a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Thank you everyone. We are in the process of upgrading to SQL Server 2017 within the next week or so.  I will wait until then and use the OFFSET FETCH clauses which should achieve the result I require.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. We are in the process of upgrading to SQL Server 2017 within the next week or so. I will wait until then and use the OFFSET FETCH clauses which should achieve the result I require.